# How to create a star schema from an initial large table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure

I currently have a single table containing 50m rows.

```
Column  Data Type
Text1   nvarchar(60)
Text2   nvarchar(115)
Text3   nvarchar(100)
Text4   nvarchar(50)
Text5   nvarchar(17)
Year    INT
Age_Group1  float
Age_Group2  float
Age_Group3  float
Age_Group4  float
Age_Group5  float
Age_Group6  float
Age_Group7  float
Age_Group8  float
Age_Group9  float
Age_Group10 float
Age_Group11 float
Age_Group12 float
Age_Group13 float
Age_Group14 float
Age_Group15 float
Age_Group16 float
Age_Group17 float
Age_Group18 float
Age_Group19 float
Age_Group20 float
Age_Group21 float
```

This data will be pulled into PowerBI using a direct query approach so I would like to ensure the data is stored in the best possible way.    Given the the size and amount of text in this table i'm thinking I should create a dimension table for each of the Text fields?

The script I have in mind is:

```
select Text1 , row_number()  OVER (         
         ORDER BY Text1 
           )  as Text1_ID   
        into Text1_DIM      
        from (  
        select distinct Text1   
        from dbo.my_table   
            ) x ;
```

I'm thinking I would do this for each of the Text fields and then create a new summarised fact table using the following:

```
select 
Text1_ID,
Text2_ID,
Text3_ID,
Text4_ID,
Text5_ID,
Year,
Age_Group1,
Age_Group2,
Age_Group3,
Age_Group4,
Age_Group5,
Age_Group6,
Age_Group7,
Age_Group8,
Age_Group9,
Age_Group10,
Age_Group11,
Age_Group12,
Age_Group13,
Age_Group14,
Age_Group15,
Age_Group16,
Age_Group17,
Age_Group18,
Age_Group19,
Age_Group20,
Age_Group21,
into My_Table_Fact
from My_Table y
join Text1 x1 on y.Text1 = x1.Text1
join Text2 x2 on y.Text2 = x1.Text2
join Text3 x3 on y.Text3 = x1.Text3
join Text4 x4 on y.Text4 = x1.Text4
join Text5 x5 on y.Text5 = x1.Text5
```

Within PowerBI i would then pull in the fact and dimension tables.

I would like to know if this the correct way of creating a star-schema from a large table and whether this is the best approach?

Comment: This will cause redundancy in the database and how will you link different text Dimensions. Also, without knowing underlying data and its granularity, we can't suggest the best approach. 

If possible share some sample rows.

Comment: As per my understanding `Age_Group...` field will contain FLAG for users age group. I would keep this information in a dimension with [Surrogate key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773011/what-is-the-difference-between-a-primary-key-and-a-surrogate-key/36773462) and refer SK as Foreign key in Fact table

Answer (score 2):

If you have a single table with 50 million rows, keyed by strings, then your approach certainly seems like a more efficient approach to storing the table -- assuming that the first five fields have lots of repeated values.

Instead of storing up to something like (60*2 + 2 + 115*2 + 2 + 100*2 + 2 + 50*2 + 2 + 17*2 + 2) = 694 bytes.  The integer columns are 20 bytes -- so there is considerable scope for space savings.

As for creating the tables themselves, I would recommend using the [`identity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function for this purpose:

```
select identity(int) as text1_id, Text1 
into Text1_DIM      
from (select distinct Text1   
      from dbo.my_table t 
     ) t
order by text1;
```

You could also put all values into a single table:

```
select identity(int) as text_id, Text
into Text1_DIM      
from (select distinct v.Text 
      from dbo.my_table t cross apply
           (values (text1), (text2), (text3), (text4), (text5)) v(text)
     ) t
order by text;
```

The only caveat is that this works when bringing in the table.  However, if the table is updated and you re-import the table, then the values along the dimension might change.  This does not really make a difference if they are only used with the one fact table.